# group by one column with full outer join oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, group-by, outer-join

I have the following query...

```
SELECT msn.id_notificacion AS notifiId, plt.planta_id AS plantaId, plt.planta_desc AS plantaDesc, orgPlt.org_id AS orgIdPlanta, 
orgPlt.org_desc AS orgDescPlanta, age.agencia_id AS agenciaId, age.agencia_desc AS agenciaDesc, orgAge.org_id AS orgIdAgencia, 
orgAge.org_desc AS orgDescAgencia, msn.user_contac AS usuario, msn.email_orig AS correo 
FROM cat_cpd_orig_ip msn 
FULL OUTER JOIN cat_plantas_erp plt ON msn.planta_id = plt.planta_id 
FULL OUTER JOIN cat_planta_loc pltLoc ON plt.planta_id = pltLoc.planta_id 
FULL OUTER JOIN cat_organizacion_adi orgPlt ON pltLoc.org_id = orgPlt.org_id 
FULL OUTER JOIN cat_agencia_erp age ON msn.agencia_id = age.agencia_id 
FULL OUTER JOIN cat_agencia_loc ageLoc ON age.agencia_id = ageLoc.agencia_id 
FULL OUTER JOIN cat_organizacion_adi orgAge ON ageLoc.org_id = orgAge.org_id 
WHERE msn.id_notificacion IS NOT NULL GROUP BY usuario ORDER BY usuario
```

But when I group the results I have the following error...

```
ORA-00904: "USUARIO": identificador no valido
00904. 00000 -  "%s: invalid identifier"
*Cause:    
*Action:
Error en la línea: 11, columna: 48
```

My query return the following results...

```
27  4570    BLM_ATITALAQUIA                     63  BARCEL                  PRUEBA PLANTA TRES  prueba.planta_3@grupobimbo.com
9   109     WM_MEXICO                           62  BIMBO                   PRUEBA PLANTA DOS   prueba.planta_2@grupobimbo.com
8   727     STE_MARINELA VILLAHERMOSA           62  BIMBO                   PRUEBA PLANTA DOS   prueba.planta_2@grupobimbo.com
29  1225    BLM_LAGUNA                          63  BARCEL                  PRUEBA PLANTA TRES  prueba.planta_3@grupobimbo.com
28  1605    BLM_CDIS OCCIDENTE                  63  BARCEL                  PRUEBA PLANTA TRES  prueba.planta_3@grupobimbo.com
3   5483    GLO_MEXICO                          64  EL GLOBO                PRUEBA PLANTA UNO   prueba.planta_1@grupobimbo.com
```

But I need the following result...

```
3   5483    GLO_MEXICO                          64  EL GLOBO                PRUEBA PLANTA UNO   prueba.planta_1@grupobimbo.com
9   109     WM_MEXICO                           62  BIMBO                   PRUEBA PLANTA DOS   prueba.planta_2@grupobimbo.com
27  4570    BLM_ATITALAQUIA                     63  BARCEL                  PRUEBA PLANTA TRES  prueba.planta_3@grupobimbo.com
```

I need to group my results by the 'usuario', can you help me?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You cannot use table aliases in a `GROUP BY` for Oracle.  So, the obvious fix to your error is:

```
GROUP BY msn.user_contac
ORDER BY msn.user_contac
```

However, that will only generate another error -- you have a zillion columns in the `SELECT` that are not aggregated and not in the `GROUP BY`.  They will cause another error.

Your question doesn't specify what you want to do.  It only mentions the `GROUP BY` error.  So, this answers your question, but it doesn't solve your problem.

You may want to ask another question with more explanation on what you are trying to do, perhaps with sample data and desired results.

Comment: I wrote more details of what I need to do in the body of the question. Thank you!